# How I can programmatically set NSWindow to full screen?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nswindow

Example when you double-click Xcode's toolbar, Xcode will automatically goes full screen (still show's menubar). How I can achieve same result programmatically using storyboards and Xcode 7 GM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mode is not called "full screen" but "zoomed".

You can "zoom" a window to the max available space by using the NSScreen visible frame as the target frame.

Let's say `window` is your NSWindow IBOutlet:

```
window.setFrame(NSScreen.mainScreen()!.visibleFrame, display: true, animate: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the swift 5 version.
In **viewWillAppear()** function of you view controller, call this function.

```
 func setWindowFrameAndCenter() {
        guard let window = self.view.window,
              let windowScreenFrame = window.screen?.visibleFrame else {
                  return
              }
        window.setFrame(windowScreenFrame,
                        display: false,
                        animate: false)
        window.center()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C:

```
[self.window setFrame:NSScreen.mainScreen.visibleFrame display: true animate: true];
```